# Where can I find the shortcut keys for netbeans php development?

Tags: php, netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts

I googled this and I found some old stuff, where can I find the keyword shortcuts for netbeans, when I'm doing php development?

Comment: Could you clarify that you are indeed looking for keyboard shortcuts and not keyword shortcuts. I take the meaning of keyword shortcuts to be Code Template Abbreviations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for the **Code Template Abbreviations** that allow you to do things like, for instance, type `do` and then press the `TAB` button and get:

```
do {

} while (true);
```

You can find all of these abbreviations under `Tools > Options > Editor[TAB] > Code Templates[TAB]`. Then to see the abbreviations for PHP you can select PHP using the `Language` combo box.

You can also add your own code templates here. See the following for the syntax for adding your own PHP code template.

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/code-templates.html#syntax

Answer (score 1):

Under options there's a keymap tab, not sure how complete that is though.